# Polymer 1: parent component not listening to a fire event from a child component's 'detached' method?

Tags: javascript, polymer, event-listener

I have a parentComponent and several childComponents like so:

```
<parent-component>
    <child-component> child_1 </child-component>
    <child-component> child_2 </child-component>
</parent-component>
```

ParentComponent:

```
Polymer({
    is: 'parent-component',
    listeners: { 
       'EVT_CHILD_ATTACHED': 'onChildAttached'
       'EVT_CHILD_DETACHED': 'onChildDetached'
    },
    onChildAttached: function () {
        console.log('child elem is ATTACHED');
    },
    onChildDetached: function () {
        console.log('child elem is DETACHED');
    }
})
```

ChildComponent:

```
Polymer({
    is: 'child-component',
    attached: function () {
        this.fire('EVT_CHILD_ATTACHED');
    },
    detached: function () {
        this.fire('EVT_CHILD_DETACHED');
    }
});
```

**Success**: When adding a *"new"* child component into the parent-component, the child-component's polymer lifecycle 'attached' method is called and the event '*EVT_CHILD_ATTACHED*' is fired and finally the parent-component is able to listen and log '*child elem is ATTACHED*' successfully.

**Failure**: When an *"existing"* child-component is removed, I can see that the child-component's polymer lifecycle 'detached' method is called and the event '*EVT_CHILD_DETACHED*' is fired as well. But the parent-component's onChildDetached() is never trigerred and there no logs shown as well.

**Qn**: How do i get the parent component to react/listen when any child component is '**detached**'?

*Notes: the child-component can be dynamically added or be wrapped under a loop-condition or dom-if condition, I have removed such logic for simplicity.*

Answer (score 0):

The `detached` event does not work the way you expect it to.

From the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements):

> **detached**
>
> Called after the element is detached from the document. Can be called
>   multiple times during the lifetime of an element. Uses include
>   removing event listeners added in `attached`.
>
> Use instead of `detachedCallback`.

Your `detached` callback is called *after* the element is detached from the DOM tree, which means that the event cannot propagate to it's parent, since it does not have one.

You will need to create a different mechanism, which does not involve firing events inside the `detached` callback.

For instance, you could hold a reference of the `parent` element inside the `child` (which you could obtain inside the `attached` callback) and then manually call the `parent`'s `onChildDetached` method inside the `child`'s `detached` event handler.

Comment: Thank you @alesc for your comments, I have figured out a way of doing this without the need to add a reference of the parent to the child. Let me know your comments if any.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Let ParentComponent add the detached method to all childComponent as soon as the child components 'attached' method fires 'EVT_CHILD_ATTACHED' and triggers the event listener in parent component like so.

```
Polymer({
    is: 'parent-component',
    listeners: { 
       'EVT_CHILD_ATTACHED': 'onChildAttached'
    },
    onChildAttached: function (evt) {
        console.log('child elem is ATTACHED');
        var self = this;
        evt.target.detached = function () {
            self.onChildDetached(this);
        }
    },
    onChildDetached: function (target) {
        console.log('child elem is DETACHED', target);
    }
})
```

Might not be the best way, but still does the job though.

Comment: You probably shouldn't register event listeners from outside of an element. This could cause future incompatibility issues. It is better that the parent calls a predefined method on the child and with it passes it's reference to the child.

Comment: I guess that will lead to tight coupling of parent and child, My goal was to have child components which does not know if its parent element, so that it is reusable when used with a different parent component (as long as it is a polymer component and follows the polymer lifecycle events). Similarly the parent component can have different 'kinds' of child-components as well. e.g. The parent component can be a carousel- component, or a tab-component, or a menu-component which just deals with manipulating its children.